# How to use the AIC/BIC for overfitting (information criteria) ARIMA

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, aic, overfitting

So I am using STATA, I have the log likelihood, AIC and BIC as such:

AIC: -112.1838
BIC: -100.2412
log likelihood: 64.23
N= 200 observations

So how do I conclude that there is no "over fitting" using these values?

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot say anything about overfitting from (log-)likelihood, AIC or BIC alone. You could say something by comparing the model's in-sample fit with its out-of-sample prediction accuracy. If the in-sample residuals are subtantially smaller than the out-of-sample forecasting errors, the model suffers from overfitting; otherwise, it does not. Time series cross validation (e.g. as presented in Hyndman & Athanasopoulos "Forecasting: Principles and Practice" [Section 5.10](https://otexts.com/fpp3/tscv.html)) is your way to go.